# No value associated with key parse json

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

Hey guys I want to decode this json data, I want to get the **city**, but it failed while the others is fine if delete the location in my model. can anyone help me this is my code.

```
"results": {
    "datetime": [
        {
            "times": {
                "Imsak": "04:07",
                "Sunrise": "05:32",
                "Fajr": "04:17",
                "Dhuhr": "11:47",
                "Asr": "15:14",
                "Sunset": "18:02",
                "Maghrib": "18:16",
                "Isha": "19:13",
                "Midnight": "23:10"
            },
            "date": {
                "timestamp": 1544659200,
                "gregorian": "2018-12-13",
                "hijri": "1440-04-06"
            }
        }
    ],
    "location": {
        "latitude": -6.2375,
        "longitude": 106.69556,
        "elevation": 26,
        "city": "Ciputat",
        "country": "Republic of Indonesia",
        "country_code": "ID",
        "timezone": "Asia/Jakarta",
        "local_offset": 7
    }
}
```

This Is my model Object where there is no value in city associated key have no value, but strangely if delete the var location under the struct results and all the associates it works fine only the location is the problem.

```
struct PrayerModel: Decodable {
   var results: Results
}

struct Results: Decodable {
   var datetime: [DateTime]
   var location: Location
}

struct Location: Decodable {
   var city: String

init(dictionary: [String: String]) {
    self.city = dictionary["city"] ?? ""
  }
}

struct DateTime: Decodable {
   var times: Times
}

struct Times: Decodable {
  var Imsak: String
  var Sunrise: String
  var Fajr: String
  var Dhuhr: String
  var Asr: String
  var Sunset: String
  var Maghrib: String
  var Isha: String
  var Midnight: String

init(dictionary: [String: String]) {
    self.Imsak = dictionary["Imsak"] ?? ""
    self.Sunrise = dictionary["Sunrise"] ?? ""
    self.Fajr = dictionary["Fajr"] ?? ""
    self.Dhuhr = dictionary["Dhuhr"] ?? ""
    self.Asr = dictionary["Asr"] ?? ""
    self.Sunset = dictionary["Sunset"] ?? ""
    self.Maghrib = dictionary["Maghrib"] ?? ""
    self.Isha = dictionary["Isha"] ?? ""
    self.Midnight = dictionary["Midnight"] ?? ""
  }
}
```

This is where my error showing up, where is the error? I can't figure it out

```
Failed to decode data: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "city", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "location", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"city\", intValue: nil) (\"city\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

Comment: may be city is missing from real response

Comment: @Sh_Khan what do you mean missing real response?

Comment: The JSON you show is the full JSON that is causing an issue, or is it just a sample? Is it the one that causes the crash? Or is it another one? What could cause the error, is that in one case there is no city value (or it's nil), and it causes the crash.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, not sure why your are using init from a dictionary with Codable

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let jsonData = """
{ 
    "results": {
        "datetime": [{
            "times": {
                "Imsak": "04:07",
                "Sunrise": "05:32",
                "Fajr": "04:17",
                "Dhuhr": "11:47",
                "Asr": "15:14",
                "Sunset": "18:02",
                "Maghrib": "18:16",
                "Isha": "19:13",
                "Midnight": "23:10"
            },
            "date": {
                "timestamp": 1544659200,
                "gregorian": "2018-12-13",
                "hijri": "1440-04-06"
            }
        }],
        "location": {
            "latitude": -6.2375,
            "longitude": 106.69556,
            "elevation": 26,
            "city": "Ciputat",
            "country": "Republic of Indonesia",
            "country_code": "ID",
            "timezone": "Asia/Jakarta",
            "local_offset": 7
        }
    }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct PrayerModel: Decodable {
    var results: Results
}

struct Results: Decodable {
    var datetime: [DateTime]
    var location: Location
}

struct Location: Decodable {
    var city: String
}

struct DateTime: Decodable {
    var times: Times
}

struct Times: Decodable {
    var Imsak: String
    var Sunrise: String
    var Fajr: String
    var Dhuhr: String
    var Asr: String
    var Sunset: String
    var Maghrib: String
    var Isha: String
    var Midnight: String
}

do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(PrayerModel.self, from: jsonData)
    print(result)

    print("city: \(result.results.location.city)")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Output:

> PrayerModel(results: __lldb_expr_53.Results(datetime: [__lldb_expr_53.DateTime(times: __lldb_expr_53.Times(Imsak: "04:07", Sunrise: "05:32", Fajr: "04:17", Dhuhr: "11:47", Asr: "15:14", Sunset: "18:02", Maghrib: "18:16", Isha: "19:13", Midnight: "23:10"))], location: __lldb_expr_53.Location(city: "Ciputat")))
>
> city: Ciputat

Comment: I try yours, but it's still showing the error no value. that's why it's confusing me. is it a bug or something?

Comment: check your response is as expected, just convert it to a string and check it.

Comment: give this a try `var city: String?`

Comment: @Sh_Khan the response is the city is nil. how come is nil?

Comment: i see you won't always get city for every lat/lon  so consider the nil case also

Comment: @Sh_Khan so how I can fix it? did you have any suggest

Comment: @ferryawijayanto if your API doesn't return the data there isn't much you can do unless you have control over the API. You could try reverse geocoding the lat/lon via a mapping API (apple built in or google will do) to lookup the lat/lon and see if you get more information back

Comment: @Scriptable the data is return but only the city is nil, did you have any suggestion? I think I will try reverse geocoding thank you.

Comment: i know.... but the API is not returning the city, it's nil. so the API doesn't have all of the data you need